# Multiplexing HID and serial on ATMega32U4

Tags: serial, usb, hid

I designed a custom **ATMega32U4** based *Arduino Leonardo* board. I'm using `MHeironimus/ArduinoJoystickLibrary` to implement an HID joystick. I need to create also a virtual serial port to send NON joystick data to the USB host (Android device).
If I try to set use the usb serial the joystick device is not recognized.
If I stop the serial the joystick works fine.
This's the code:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Joystick.h>

#define JOYSTICK_PERIOD 20

const int BUTTON1_PIN = 4;
const int BUTTON2_PIN = 5;

int x = 0, y = 0, rx = 0, ry = 0, din = 0;
long time1, time2;

Joystick_ Joystick(
  JOYSTICK_DEFAULT_REPORT_ID, 
  JOYSTICK_TYPE_GAMEPAD,
  2, 0,
  true, true, false,
  true, true, false,
  false, false,
  false, false, false
);

void setup()
{
  pinMode(4, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(5, INPUT_PULLUP);

  pinMode(A0, INPUT);
  pinMode(A1, INPUT);
  pinMode(A2, INPUT);
  pinMode(A3, INPUT);

  Joystick.begin();
  Joystick.setXAxisRange(0, 1000);
  Joystick.setYAxisRange(0, 1000);
  Joystick.setRxAxisRange(0, 1000);
  Joystick.setRyAxisRange(0, 1000);
  
  time1 = millis();

  Serial1.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void SerialEvent()
{
  int _count = Serial.available();

  for(int _i=0;_i<_count;_i++)
    Serial1.write(Serial.read());
}

void Serial1Event()
{
  int _count = Serial1.available();

  for(int _i=0;_i<_count;_i++)
    Serial.write(Serial1.read());
}

void loop() 
{
  time2 = millis();

  long _period = time2 - time1;

  time2 = time1;

  if(_period >= JOYSTICK_PERIOD)
  {
    din = (digitalRead(BUTTON1_PIN) << 1) | digitalRead(BUTTON2_PIN);

    x = analogRead(A0);
    y = analogRead(A1);
    rx = analogRead(A2);
    ry = analogRead(A3);

    Joystick.setButton(0, din);

    Joystick.setXAxis(x);
    Joystick.setYAxis(y);
    Joystick.setRxAxis(rx);
    Joystick.setRyAxis(ry);
  }
}
```

Anyone has hints?

Comment: Page not found. Please post your code here, not a link to it.

Comment: @Majenko ops the repository is private .. my fault.. I posted the code thnx.

Comment: it may be a limitation of android

Comment: this may help ... https://github.com/NicoHood/HID

Comment: https://github.com/NicoHood/HoodLoader2

Comment: @jsotola, HoodLoader is for 16u2 on Uno/Mega